# static methods and recognitions

Tags: c#, methods

I am very new to C# and programming in general, I am trying to write a simple transfer program involving a checking and savings account, I cant seem to get my main body to recognize my 2nd class that I created, It recognizes the first class just fine, any help would be appreciated.

```
public static void Main(string [] args)
{
    string shouldContinue = "yes";
    Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the savings calculator!");
    Console.WriteLine("Before we begin, we just need some information.");       
    while(shouldContinue == "yes")
    {
    BankAccount myAccount = new BankAccount();
    Console.WriteLine("How much is in your checking account today?");
    myAccount.Checking = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("How much is in your savings account today?");
    myAccount.Savings = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("How much would you like to transfer today?");
    myAccount.Balance = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine();        
    Console.WriteLine("The new balance in the checking account is: " + Transfer.newCheckBalance);
    Console.WriteLine();        
    Console.WriteLine("The new balance in the savings account is " + Transfer.newSaveBalance);
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Would you like to continue?");
    Console.WriteLine("Answer yes or no: " );       
    shouldContinue = Console.ReadLine();
}
    Console.WriteLine("Have a great day!"); 
}   
class BankAccount
{
    public int Checking;
    public int Savings;
    public int Balance;
            
    public int getChecking()
    {
        return this.Checking;
    }
    public void setChecking(int checkBalance)
    {
        this.Checking = checkBalance;
    }
    public int getSavings()
    {
        return this.Savings;
    }
    public void setSavings(int saveBalance)
    {
        this.Savings = saveBalance;
    }
    public int getBalance()
    {
        return this.Balance;
    }
    public void setBalance(int Balance2)
    {
        this.Balance = Balance2;
    }
}
    
class Transfer
{       
     static void Transfers(int checkBalance , int saveBalance , int Balance2)
    {
         int newCheckBalance = checkBalance - Balance2;
         int newSaveBalance = saveBalance + Balance2;                       
    }       

}
```

}

Comment: newCheckBalance and newSaveBalance are local variables. They cannot be used outside the block in which they are defined. Look at how you declare the variables in the BankAccount

Comment: Your first order problem is that the variables you are trying to refer to are _local_ variables in the `Transfers()` method. See duplicate for how to fix that. That said, you have other problems with the code, such as not even calling the `Transfers()` method in the first place, and the use of a static method for what likely ought to be a non-static method and object.

Comment: There are several strange things in your code. You should be using [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties) not messing around with methods of public fields.